# How to access fields value in views-view--[viewid]--[view-display-id].html.twig template

Tags: views, 8, theming

I'm trying to customize a View in Drupal 8 where I display a Bootstrap Carousel.
What I've managed to do so far was the right template name, by specifying the *viewid* and *view-display-id*. 
The view name is `homepage-carousel` and the view display id is `block 1`, therefore the template name `views-view--homepage-carousel-block-1.html.twig` or `views-view--homepage-carousel.html.twig`.

Now I need to show the content of the fields of a specific *Content Type*. I've tried with `{{ fields.title }}`, but it doesn't work. I've also tried to change the template name in `views-view-fields--homepage-carousel-block-1.html.twig`, but the system doesn't recognize it, so it displays the default view.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="carousel-fill" style="background-image:url({{file_url(field_carousel_image.entity.fileuri)}});">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 class="carousel-title">{{ fields.title }}</h3>

          {{ fields.field_carousel_subtitle }}
      </div>
</div>
```

How can I show the fields from this kind of view template?

**UPDATE** 
I've tried to rename the template as suggested [JeremyM4n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/98759/jeremym4n), I've flushed all the cache, but it still doesn't work. The view is displayed as default, namely how it is set up in the `/admin/structure/views/view/` section.

I haven't mentioned it yet, so I specify it here: the *format* of this view is **Bootstrap Carousel**

**UDPATE 2**

I managed to find a solution by by overriding the `views-bootstrap-carousel.html.twig` template in `view_bootstrap` module. In my case, the name of the template is the following: `views-bootstrap-carousel--homepage-carousel--block-1.html.twig`

Here is the code:

```
<div id="{{ id }}" class="carousel {{ effect }}"
    data-interval="{{ interval }}"
    {% if ride %} data-ride="carousel" {% endif %}
    data-pause="{% if pause %}hover{% else %}false{% endif %}">

  {# Show indicators if set in view. #}
  {%  if indicators %}
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      {% for key, row in rows %}
          {% set indicator_classes = [loop.first ? 'active'] %}
          <li class="{{ indicator_classes|join(' ') }}" data-target="#{{ id }}" data-slide-to="{{ key }}"></li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ol>
  {% endif %}

  {# Carousel body. #}
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for row in rows %}
      {% set row_classes = ['item', loop.first ? 'active'] %}
      <div class="{{ row_classes|join(' ') }}">
        <div class="carousel-fill">
          {{ row.image }}
          {% if row.title or row.description %}
            {%  if use_caption %}
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            {% endif %}
              {% if row.title %}
                  <h3 class="carousel-title">{{ row.title }}</h3>
              {% endif %}
              {% if row.description %}
                  <p>{{ row.description }}</p>
              {% endif %}
              <a class="btn btn-glass" href={{ row.field_carousel_button_url }}>{{ row.field_carousel_button_text }}</a>
            {%  if use_caption %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {# Controls #}
  {% if navigation %}
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#{{ id }}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">{{ 'Previous'|t }}</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#{{ id }}" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">{{ 'Next'|t }}</span>
    </a>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: No, I've tried to use that kind of template, but it seems it is not recognized.

Comment: See the answer below, you're missing a second dash `-` before `block` as you need to have two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template name needs double dashes between each section `views-view--homepage-carousel--block-1.html.twig.`

At the views-view level all of your data is in `rows`. You would need to loop through your rows and then get the fields. But it's much easier to just override the main structure you need to in `views-view`, and then use `views-view-fields--homepage-carousel--block-1.html.twig` to change the structure of the actual fields, in which case they are available under `fields` like your example code.

Comment: Should I create `views-view.html.twig` first and then `views-view-fields--homepage-carousel--block-1.html.twig` in the same folder?

Comment: views-view.html.twig would override all views, but as a troubleshooting method I would test the simplest change first. First verify your theme is working ( where you're placing the templates), then make a simple, visible change, like adding a <h2>Test</h2> to the views-view template and see if it works. Also you mentioned the format is bootstrap carousel, so it probably has it's own template in that module that you may need to override.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your answer. I was able to access those fields by overriding the `views-bootstrap-carousel.html.twig` template in `view_bootstrap` module. In my case, the name of the template is the following: `views-bootstrap-carousel--homepage-carousel--block-1.html.twig`